# VBA Excel macro: keeping and deleting sheets based on data in cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

This may be a very simple question but I can't figure it out. I run a macro that creates 13 spreadsheets. Of those 13 spreads, several of them won't have anything in column A2. I would like to be able to create a macro in VBA that will delete all spreads with nothing in A2 but keep the spreads that have data in A2. I've tried using:

```
Sub Delete()
Dim ws As Worksheet
  For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
      If LenB(ActiveSheet.Range("A2")) = 0 Then ActiveSheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Next ws
End Sub
```

This deletes the active sheet if nothing is in A2 so that's some progress for me but it won't automatically move to the next sheet.

Comment: You should everywhere use `ws` instead of `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Yes! That works. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Sly please consider marking Máté Juhász Answer as accepted

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't consistent, you should everywhere use `ws` instead of `ActiveSheet`.